# Insert multiple records from datagridview to SQL server database

Tags: c#

I have a project in C# which the user can choose only one row in datagridview and fill it's data by filling textboxes, but that takes a long time to do, so how can I develop the below code that user can choose a group of names (which the same data should be recorded) by select several rows in datagridview to insert data into SQL server database?
this the code I use after select a separate row:

```
        {
            hour.ADD_ADDITIONAL_HOURS(Convert.ToInt32(txtRecID.Text), dtDateFrom.Value.Date, dgActiveEmps.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(cmbSymboles.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(txtHours.Text));
        }
```

note: ADD_ADDITIONAL_HOURS is a stored procedure

Comment: Which database and version are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server 2019 database

Comment: You are going to need to explain things better. What does _"which I can record data for each row in the datagridview separately"_ mean? The only code you show is a call to a method named `ADD_ADDITIONAL_HOURS` on an instance of some class (the instance is in a variable named `hour`). What does that have to do with a DataGridView or a stored procedure?

Comment: First hour is not a variable, it is an object coppied from the main class where the method is stored. Now there is no problem but I want to select several rows and run the method instead of one row and run the method

Comment: What do you mean by "record"?

Comment: "record" means Assigning the same entry order  to several rows in the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use table valued parameters.  To do this, firstly create a user defined table type in SQL Server thus:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.YourTypeName AS TABLE  
(  
   [ID] [nvarchar(50)] 
)
```

(I am assuming that your Cells[0].value contains a string.  If it is another data type, then change the type of ID above appropriately).

Next change the third parameter of your stored procedure to `<parameter_name> AS dbo.YourTypeName READONLY)`.  Within the body of your procedure, change the update(?) statement to be based on a join with this parameter - you use it like any other table.  It should look something like:

```
UPDATE t
SET col1 = @param1 ....
FROM YourTable t INNER JOIN @tablevaluedparameter tvp ON tvp.ID = t.ID
```

Turning to c#, you need to change the third parameter passed to the stored procedure to be `SqlDbType.Structured`.  Finally you need to populate the parameter with the values from `SelectedRows`.  Here you have a choice: the values can be placed in any of `DataTable`, `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` or `DbDataReader`; all of these can be the `Value` property of the parameter.

For example, using a `DataTable` your code would look something like this:

```
var dT = new DataTable();
dT.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0: i < dgActiveEmps.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
{
    dT.Rows.Add(dgActiveEmps.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
} 

yourSqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@tablevaluedparameter",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
    Value = dT,
    TypeName = "dbo.YourTypeName"
});
```

Obviously you will need to adapt the namings to fit your case, but I hope it should be clear what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, it took me some time to process your previous words and try to get done

Comment: If you need more help with specifics, please edit your question, to include the bits where you are having difficulty.